# MuleESB AnyPointStudio JPA implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mule, esb

I'm using the CE Mule Server 3.5.0, and AnyPoint Studio as IDE.

I just can't find a way to implement the JPA with EntityManager; honestly there aren't tutorials or explanations on how to do that, how to put a DS in the MuleServer or use DBconnector as DS...just don't know...

I can guess that my persistence.xml goes in the src/main/resource of my project, but not sure of that too.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks 4 coop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the following example?:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-jpa-and-mule

Answer (score 0):

Good example available in Mule in Action book Appendix D.

Code available here:

https://github.com/ddossot/mule-in-action-2e/tree/master/appendixD